# Individually styling javascript output of a countdown timer

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to style the output of a javascript date counter. I need to be able to style the days, hours, minutes & seconds separately. I want to right align each in it's own div with it's own left and top absolute values. When I try to do that the timer does not replace the previous numbers, but adds to them, creating a big mess.

Here's the output code I am trying to style individually:

```
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = days + 'days ';
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += hours + 'hrs ';
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += minutes + 'mins ';
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += seconds + 'secs';
```

[Here's a fiddle of it working fine but without separate styling](http://jsfiddle.net/SquareGiraffe/vmad261a/)

But, when I try to put them in separate divs crazy stuff happens, haha. The counter does not update, but just adds numbers instead.
[Here's a fiddle of that](http://jsfiddle.net/SquareGiraffe/1dzuy7wc/)

How do I do this?

Comment: You can wrap the contents for the innerHTML values and then style it.

Comment: They are separate elements, remove + from your += code.

Comment: @ManojKumar Please explain how?

Comment: @Jules when I try that it only prints the seconds.

Comment: I've updated it for you.  http://jsfiddle.net/1dzuy7wc/8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are inserting the `innerHTML` values to the div, you can wrap the values inside a `span` with a class.

[**JSfiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/vmad261a/14/)

```
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = '<span class="days">' + days + 'days ';
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += '<span class="hours">' + hours + 'hrs ';
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += '<span class="minutes">' + minutes + 'mins ';
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += '<span class="seconds">' + seconds + 'secs';
```

```js
CountDownTimer('01/01/2016 10:01 AM', 'countdown');

function CountDownTimer(dt, id) {
  var end = new Date(dt);

  var _second = 1000;
  var _minute = _second * 60;
  var _hour = _minute * 60;
  var _day = _hour * 24;
  var timer;

  function showRemaining() {
    var now = new Date();
    var distance = end - now;
    if (distance < 0) {

      clearInterval(timer);
      document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = 'EXPIRED!';

      return;
    }
    var days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);

    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = '<span class="days">' + days + 'days ';
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += '<span class="hours">' + hours + 'hrs ';
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += '<span class="minutes">' + minutes + 'mins ';
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += '<span class="seconds">' + seconds + 'secs';
  }

  timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);
}
```

```css
#countdown {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  color: #ff0000;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 32px;
  display: inline;
}
.days {
  color: lightblue;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  padding: 10px;
}
.minutes {
  color: tomato;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  padding: 10px;
}
.seconds {
  color: gray;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  padding: 10px;
}
.hours {
  color: tomato;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="countdown">


</div>
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you.  I tried this earlier but I wrote `+ '<span class="hours">' += hours + 'hrs '; ` Which did not work :D  What does the += mean in this context?

Comment: `+=` is equivalent to adding to already existent content.  `a += 6;` means `a = a+6;`

Comment: You can check for your web console for the errors. In this context, I got this: `ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side
 

ument.getElementById(id).innerHTML + '<span class="hours">' += hours + 'hrs ';` which means you were trying to add to multiple operands on the left side which are yet to be calculated.

Answer (score 1):

If you will remove the line

```
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = days + 'days ';
```

You will see "creating a big mess.". You must clear the div before put something to them.

```
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = '';
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding all your time elements to a single I'd,  create 4 separate divs inside the div you already have. Then use getElementById to put each time element inside it's own div.

That will allow you to use css to style each individually.